# Convergence of sequence defined by recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_{n+1} =\dfrac 1k [a_n + k/a_n]$ where $k$ is greater than $1$ and $a_1>0$.
Show that sequence a_n is convergent.

Comment: hi - you might try to experiment a bit. For example choose $k=2$ and $a_1=1$. Then you'd have a concrete sequence to examine.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{k}+\dfrac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$. Notice that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, so the sequence is obtained by starting with $a_0$ and applying $f$ repeatedly.

We will analyze the function $f$. Note that
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$
is negative for $0<x<\sqrt{k}$ and positive for $x>\sqrt{k}$. Hence $f$ has a global minimum at $x=\sqrt{k}$. Moreover, $f(\sqrt{k})=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Let $\alpha$ be any value larger than both $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}}$ and $\dfrac{\sqrt{k}}{k-1}$ (which of these is larger will depend on whether $\sqrt{k}$ is greater than or smaller than $2$). Consider the interval $I=I_\alpha=[\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}},\alpha]$. Let us prove that $f(I)\subseteq I$.

Indeed, if $x\in I$ then $f(x)\geq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}}$, since this is the minimum that $f$ attains. On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sqrt{k}}{k-1}\leq \alpha
&\iff\sqrt{k}\leq\alpha k-\alpha\\
&\iff2\sqrt{k}+\alpha-\sqrt{k}\leq\alpha k\\
&\iff \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}}+\dfrac{1}{k}(\alpha-\sqrt{k})\leq\alpha\tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
Our assumption on $\alpha$ assures that the first inequality is valid, so ($*$) is also valid. Moreover, we have $f'<\dfrac{1}{k}$ globally, so the Mean Value Theorem yields
\begin{align*}
f(x)&\leq f(\sqrt{k})+\dfrac{1}{k}(x-\sqrt{k})\\
&\leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}}+\dfrac{1}{k}(\alpha-\sqrt{k})\\
&\leq\alpha
\end{align*}
by ($*$). Therefore $f(I)\subseteq I$, as we wanted.

---

Now back to our initial problem. Let $\alpha$ be sufficiently large so that $a_1<\alpha$. Consider the interval $I_\alpha$. Then since the sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is obtained by applying $f$ and $f(I_\alpha)\subseteq I_\alpha$, we have that all $a_i$ belong to $I_\alpha$, except possibly for $a_0$.

Then $f'\leq\dfrac{1}{k}<1$ on $I_\alpha$, since $k>1$, and $f(I_\alpha)\subseteq I_\alpha$.

By (one of the usual proofs of) the Banach Fixed Point Theorem, the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}_n$ converges (to a fixed point of $f$).

---

Here are the details of the proof: Let $f^i(x)=f(f(f\cdots f(x)))$ denote the function obtained by applying $f$ consecutively $i$ times.

By the Mean Value Theorem, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k^{-1}|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$, and more generally |f^i(x)-f^i(y)|\leq k^{-i}|x-y|$.

Thus for $n>m>1$,
\begin{align*}
|a_n-a_m|&\leq\sum_{i=m+1}^n|a_{i+1}-a_i|\\
&=\sum_{i=m+1}^n|f^i(a_1)-f^{i-1}(a_1)|\\
&\leq\sum_{i=m+1}^nk^{-(i-1)}|f(a_1)-a_1|\\
&<\leq\sum_{j=m}^\infty k^{-j}|a_2-a_1|\\
&=\dfrac{k^{-m}}{k^{-1}-1}|a_2-a_1|.
\end{align*}
Taking $m$ sufficiently large makes the last term small (since $k>1$). So the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is Cauchy, and therefore converges.

Comment: In order to apply Banach Fixed Point Theorem it is necessary that $$ is a contraction mapping and so you need to prove that $|′()|\le\frac{1}{k}<1$, but you only proved that $′()\le\frac{1}{k}<1$.

Comment: $f(x)\le f\left(\sqrt k\right)+\frac{1}{k}\left(x-\sqrt k \right)$ is correct if $x-\sqrt k \ge0$ (in fact $f’(x)$ can be negative), but if $k>2$, $x-\sqrt k$ can result negative for some values $x\in I_{\alpha}$.